# Objective-c how to update UI depending on background process

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, reachability

I'm working on an iPad app and I ran into an issue. I use Reachability to check if the device is connected to a network (which works fine) and I want to update an image view to pass it from wifi icon to no wifi icon when network get disconnected. So I found that I could do a background process that constantly check if the device is connected just like that:

```
// Allocate a reachability object
Reachability* reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

// Set the blocks
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        connectivity = true;
        NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");
    });
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    connectivity = false;
    NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
};
// Start the notifier, which will cause the reachability object to retain itself!
[reach startNotifier];
```

This works but I don't know where to put my image modification to make it work properly because if I put it before the NSLog(), I get "imageView setImage must be used from main thread only"

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must update the UI on the main thread. To do so, you should call `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` when you detect that the wifi was connected/disconnected and then update your image accordingly. Like so:

```
reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        connectivity = true;
        NSLog(@"REACHABLE!");
        [yourImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"withWifi"]];
    });
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        connectivity = false;
        NSLog(@"UNREACHABLE!");
        [yourImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noWifi"]];
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

inside the `dispatch_async` is the right place. You need to add a similar block in the `unreachableBlock`.

As the error msg said, you can modify the Ui only from the main thread.